# скролл внутри слайда на swiper.js

Tags: прокрутка, swiper, mobile, touch

Всем привет. Делаю следующий функционал: вертикальный swiper.js, первые две секции растянуты на 100vh, последняя секция имеет внутренний скролл с собственным контентом. Реализовал следующим способом данный функционал, но на мобильных устройствах багует и не работает. Возможно есть другой способ решения или есть возможность решить баг на мобильных устройствах. Спасибо.

```js
  const topSlider = new Swiper('.sliderPage .swiper', {
    speed: 600,
    direction: 'vertical',
    modules: [Mousewheel],
    mousewheel: true,
    mousewheel: {
      noMousewheelClass: 'nowheel',
      releaseOnEdges: true,
    },
  });

  const lastSlide = document.querySelector('.swiper-slide-3');

  lastSlide.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    if (lastSlide.scrollTop > 0 ) {
      lastSlide.classList.add('nowheel');
    } else if (lastSlide.scrollTop === 0) {
      lastSlide.classList.remove('nowheel');
    }
  })
```

```css
.sliderPage {
  height: 100vh;
  .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
    &-slide {
      // height: 100vh !important;
      &-1 {

      }
      &-2 {
        
      }

      &-3 {
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<section class="sliderPage">
  <div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-1">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-2">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-3">Тут секция с прокруткой lorem*100</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```